# Set focus in JS with accessibility - voiceOver IOS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, focus, accessibility, voiceover

I am not able to set focus on an element when IOS accessibility - voiceOver is set. When navigating on my site, the element that is read is the element closest to the navigation button on the last page. I want it to set focus on a specific h tag that is the title of the page.

Things I have tried:

- js id and focus() method when vue is mounted
- vue ref and focus() method when vue is mounted
- same as both above but with select() as well

Stack:
Laravel, Jetstream, Vue, Inertia

Simplified example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 ref="title">My Page Title</h1>
        <p>
            Some lorem ipsum text   
        </p>
        <p>
            Some more lorem ipsum text   
        </p>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        this.$refs.title.focus(); // This does not work for voiceOver
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Added a example and the "specific h tag" that I mentioned is referring to the ref="title" in the example. Does that make it clearer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As horrible as the solution is I have a solution to the problem. Changed the h1 tag with a input tag, changed the role to "text" and put a "readonly" on it.

Solution with tailwind classes:

```
<input role="text" value="My text header" class="font-bold outline-none bg-transparent" readonly autofocus>
```

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. For accessibility reasons this is not a valid solution.

Answer (score 2):

When focusing any element that is not designed to receive focus you should add a `tabindex` to it to make it focusable.

Now as this is a heading we do not want it adding to the focus order on the page as that would not be logical, (i.e. you can't <kbd>Tab</kbd> to it) so you should add `tabindex="-1"`.

"Negative one" on a `tabindex` essentially tells the browser "allow me to focus this programatically, but do not add it to the focus order of the page".

Comment: Tried it out but it did not work. The focus is still not set.